# Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, exception, facebook-c#-sdk

My code:

```
 var fbWebContext = FacebookWebContext.Current;
 if (fbWebContext.IsAuthorized())
 {
      var fb = new FacebookWebClient(fbWebContext);
      dynamic result = fb.Get("/me");

      name.Text = result.name;
 }

 dynamic result = fb.Get("/me");
```

throws:

> (OAuthException) Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.

How should I change my code to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask for the "offline_access" extended permission. This will prevent this message and the user does not have to log in each time.

Comment: offline_access is now deprecated and will be removed by May, 2012.

Comment: @wize, is there an alternative?

Comment: @jeremy-patrick: Yes, the Facebook standard way is a re-authentication. How to do that depends on which client-side platform you use. My client-side platform is Android, which means I have to call authorize on the Facebook Android SDK whenever the access token expires. Facebook has [official info on their webpage](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/)

Answer (score 2):

You really can't prevent it, you just need to catch the exception and deal with it.  Well Ok you could prevent it I guess on the client side by doing some equivalent calls from the FB Javascript SDK to detect a bad session (expired, logged off, user changed their password, etc.) and get them to log in again on the client before your server-side code is invoked.

If you look at the Facebook C# SDK source code you can see that IsAuthorized() = IsAuthenticated().  All IsAuthenticated does is check to see if you have a Session, and that the Session's expiration time hasn't passed.  The Session could have been invalidated by the user logging off unbeknownst to the server.

There are other Facebook OAuth exceptions you can get here too.  It is best to wrap the above code in a try/catch and deal with the exceptions by re-prompting the user to log in and get a fresh session with them.

Answer (score 0):

What about the CanvasAnthorizer object ? Doesn't this object ensures that the user is logged and with the correct permissions ?

Comment: It is still possible for the user logs out of FB on another browser tab and thereby invalidate the access token on the tab used by the app.  I have tested this scenario and it does result in the above OAuth exception.

Comment: What are you doing in such a scenario? I have this problem even if the user logs back in, even if i restart the application afte he logs back in

Comment: I throw up little alert message boxes that alert them to the problem and prompt them to login again.  This depends on them coming back to one of my app's pages.  Some users get email from my app, and I put a note at the top of the email if they have a token/OAuth problem.  You need to get their attention and give them a button to click on that will get a fresh session/token.