# facebooker2 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker2

I am using facebooker2 gem on Ruby on Rails 2.3.8.

This works very well. However now when i try connect with a user this error is thrown.

```
Mogli::Client::OAuthException (Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.):
```

I don´t understand why this occurs.

is the `api key` the `api id` as well?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

Now I can see the problem. There is a bug with sessions/cookies. If I delete the cookies I can connect correctly. However if I disconnect and then reconnect the same error is thrown

I use fb_logout helper. However how can I delete the Facebook sessions? how can I prevent/catch/rescue this error?

Thanks in advance again.

Comment: IF you need more details post a comment

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167194/error-validating-access-token-the-session-is-invalid-because-the-user-logged-out

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? and how ? I'm facing the exact same situation and I'm kind of stuck here. thanks

Comment: Are you deleting your cookies or are you deleting facebook's session cookies?